# WKWebView content not resizing properly

Tags: ios, swift, resize, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` which loads HTML5 games. The HTML5 games resize perfectly when opening them in safari on my mac, without a problem. However, when I change the orientation of my iPad Pro and thus resize the size of the `UICollectionViewCells`, the `WebView` containing the `WKWebView` also gets resized. Unfortunately, not the game.

In the image below, I gave the `WKWebView` a backgroundColor of `UIColor.red` so its easy to distinguish.

[image: Example]

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

final class WebView: UIView {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    var bounces: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            webView.scrollView.bounces = bounces
        }
    }

    override var bounds: CGRect {
        didSet {
            if webView != nil {
                var b = bounds
                b.origin.x = 0
                b.origin.y = 0

                webView.bounds = b
                webView.frame = b
            }
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: 100), configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        addSubview(webView)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        webView.frame = rect
    }

    /// Load request
    func load(_ request: URLRequest) {
        webView.load(request)
    }

}
```

What is it I am doing wrong, or better yet... how can I tell the WKWebView to resize without reloading the webview.

**Update:**
If I lock the device (on/off button) and unlock the device, resuming, the content resizes properly and looks correct.

**Update:**
When decreasing the size of the `UICollectionViewCell`, the contents resizes nicely. But it doesn't when increasing the size.

Also tried resizing subclasses, which didn't help either, using:

```
override var bounds: CGRect {
    didSet {
        if webView != nil {
            var b = bounds
            b.origin.x = 0
            b.origin.y = 0

            webView.bounds = b
            webView.frame = b

            for item in webView.subviews {
                item.bounds = b

                if item.subviews.count > 0 {
                    setBounds(toSubView: item, toBounds: b)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func setBounds(toSubView subView: UIView, toBounds bounds: CGRect) {
    for item in subView.subviews {
        if item.subviews.count > 0 {
            setBounds(toSubView: item, toBounds: bounds)
        }

        if item.classIdentifier == "WKContentView" {
            item.bounds = bounds
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: I believe I solved it by resizing after a delay. Quite a while ago and changed jobs since... so can't say for sure anymore.